# How do I find a block containing 2 tags in a loop?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape the contents of the following html and want to capture the h2 then each

until the next h2 using beautiful soup. Is this possible?

```
<hr /><h2>California</h2>
<p><strong>Term 1:</strong> (Eastern division): Tuesday 29 January — 
Friday 
12 April</p>
<p><strong>Term 1:</strong> (Western division): Tuesday 5 February — 
Friday 
12 April</p>
<p><strong>Term 2</strong><strong>:</strong> Monday 29 April — Friday 5 
July</p>
<p><strong>Term 3:</strong> Monday 22 July — Friday 27 September</p>
<p><strong>Term 4:</strong> Monday 14 October — Friday 20 December</p>

<hr /><h2>New York</h2>
<p><strong>Term 1</strong>: Tuesday 29 January — Friday 12 April</p>
<p><strong>Term 2:</strong> Monday 29 April — Friday 5 July</p>
<p><strong>Term 3</strong>: Monday 22 July — Friday 27 September</p>
<p><strong>Term 4</strong>: Monday 14 October — Friday 13 December</p>
</pre>

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
for each_div in soup.findAll(['h2', 'p']):
myval = str(each_div.prettify("ascii"))
```

I want to get the following results for each state

Comment: The content of the HTML is as follows just before the list.
 <div class="content">

    <div class="field field-name-field-body field-type-text-long field-label-hidden"><div 
    class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">

Comment: Your question seems to have been cut off at the end; what's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I think you should be able to work with. The list `capture` 
keeps track of the elements you want for each header. The code is using the 
`find_next_siblings` [method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get all of the siblings in the tree and iterate
over them. When it reaches another `h2` tag, it breaks.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')    
for head in soup.find_all('h2'):
    capture = [head]
    for sibling in head.find_next_siblings():
        if sibling.name == 'h2':
            break
        capture += [sibling]
```

I would just change how you store off the captured tags.

Edit: Forgot to mention that `content` is the html string provided in
your question.